# VBA Selection.offset(0,18) as an object, but it moves too far

Tags: excel, vba, object, offset

My vba code requires me to move 18 cells to the right.
Since I use "Selection.offset(0,18)" a lot, I decided to turn into into a variable.
But every time I use "MoveEighteen.select" it will move about 50 cells to the right. This only happens after the IF statements. The very first MoveEighteen works fine.

```vb
   Dim AnchorDate As Range
    Dim CompareDate As Range
    Dim MoveEighteen As Range
    Set AnchorDate = Range("b2")
    Set MoveEighteen = Selection.Offset(0, 18)

    Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=int(NOW())"
    Range("B2").Copy
    Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B5").Select


    If Selection = AnchorDate Then
    MoveEighteen.Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select`


    Do Until Selection <> AnchorDate
    MoveEighteen.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'go tonext date
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
    Loop
    
    Else: Selection.Select
    
    Else: Selection.Select
        If Selection < AnchorDate Then
            Do Until Selection = AnchorDate
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Loop
        End If
        
        If Selection = AnchorDate Then
        MoveEighteen.Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False`
```

Comment: `Set MoveEighteen = Selection.Offset(0, 18)` - this only runs *once*, so you `MoveEighteen` will always be the same range.  You best bet to fix your code is to not use Select/Activate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

Might not understand how you're using it, but turning it into a variable makes it static, you may want a function instead?

```
Function MoveEighteen(target As Range) as Range
Set MoveEighteen = target.offset(0,18)
End Function
```

<s>I think the unexplaned movement of the reference is a result of your paste command? I know formulas do that sort of thing when you paste, but not sure if VBA does this too. After testing, not sure this is the case.</s>

Comment: I realize setting this as an object will only work once. I would have to set Moveeighteen every time I want to use MoveEighteen... which defeats the purpose of using MoveEighteen. Is there any way to make sure set objects dont remove their value after its used?